# Swap Spread Positions with Duration Bias

Tags: interest-rates, trading, interest-rate-swap, treasuries

In practice, how are swap spread positions actually sized and constructed between the two legs? I would suppose the two legs are simply matched in notional terms.

However, in practice, do traders ever attempt to run some sort of swap spread position with a duration bias? For example, having a swap spread widener on with slightly more dv01 on the pay fixed swap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, generally you want it dv01 hedged not notional hedged to capture the spread changes in basis points.

Comment: Thanks Edward. Do you have any insight on whether in practice, trades sometimes run a duration bias by underhedging or over hedging one of the legs?

Comment: Maybe, people use all types of different hedging strategies including principal component analysis, regressions, dv01. Many swap and curve trades are directional so you might have a duration bias, but probably not for the purposes of having an explicit duration bias.